# How to use the "All Exceptions" breakpoint for exceptions outside @try {} @catch {}?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, exception, breakpoints

In Xcode, you can go to the Breakpoints tab, then add a breakpoint for "All Exceptions".

I find this very helpful, but is it possible for this to break the program **only** when the exception is **not handled** by a `@try {} @catch {}` in my code? Those are the only ones that interest me.

It would be even nicer if I could select specific files where I'm interested in using this breakpoint system, although I'm guessing that's a bit too much to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is breaking on abort; it will print the exception and backtrace in the log before breaking. You may also have luck setting your own unhandled exception handler and breaking on that.

If you really want to use All Exceptions the way you described, please file a bug with apple:

http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Unhandled exception handler works great. You can use `-[NSException callStackSymbols]` for the stack trace of the exact moment the exception was raised. This will work for Objective C exceptions only. You can also register signal handlers for signal exceptions.